# How to send and save Data via URL using Retrofit and Django rest-framework

Tags: android, json, django-rest-framework, retrofit2

I'm working on an Android Application and I want to be able to manage the users ( Adding , Updating , Deleting, Displaying ) . I'm using Retrofit Client and Django-Rest-Framework . All my users info are accessible via 127.0.0.1:8000/users/?format=json URL . I already managed to display all my users in a ListView and now I'm want to be able to add the informations concerning my users in the android app so that they are displayed when I access the URL in question . I hope I explained it well . Any Recommendations ?

Answer (score 0):

From the look of things.. your ID field is unique!

So your problem can be solved by creating another page, we call it *edit.php*.
This page will contain code to edit your database based on the id. Here is a sample code which can help.

```
<?php
  function makeChanges(){
      $database = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydatabase;", "admin", "password");
      $database -> exec("INSERT INTO `users`(`nom`, `prenom`, `cne`, `email`, `tel`) VALUES('" . $_GET['nom']. "', '"  . $_GET['prenom'] . "', '" . $_GET['cne'] . "', '" . $_GET['email'] . "', '" . $_GET['tel'] . "') WHERE `id`='" . $_GET['id'] . "'");
      echo "User with id " . $_GET['id'] . " has been edited successfully";
      $database = null; //Destroy the database object
   }
  makeChanges();


?>
```

That there basically takes requests via HTTP GET and now finds the user with the id and edits the info to match the one in the request.

So from your android app, you use access http://127.0.0.1/edit.php?id=1&nom=Tom&prenom=him&email=someone@here.com&tel=6541900400&cne=A32ADE3

Comment: For example , I have a view which contains two Text Fields : say Name and Sex for instance . When I enter the informations concerning the new user , I want this data to be saved so that i can see it in 127.0.0.1:8000/users/?format=json

Comment: No , I don't think you really understood me ...
My data is stored on the server , I just want to modify the data related to my users through the android application

Comment: When I access 127.0.0.1/users : It displays this page [sample image](https://imgur.com/49cFdFE) . This are the users that are actually stored in my database .

Comment: the newly added users should also be displayed when i access this URL .

Comment: that answers my question but i'm not using php ,is there any way to do this operation with django-rest-framework ?

Comment: Oh great! sorry I'm new to it